# Convert query from SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to convert this SQL query to LINQ:

```
SELECT COUNT(result1.Id) AS total, 
    result1.OccurrenceDate, 
    result1.Path, 
    result1.Message, 
    result1.StackTrace 
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbllog ORDER BY OccurrenceDate DESC) AS result1
GROUP BY result1.Path, result1.Message ORDER BY total DESC
```

But I'm not getting success. I've tried in so many ways, nothing works.
Some help?

Comment: if you could add some of your tries we could help you

Comment: Look, I need to group some errors which is stored on table tbllog, and I just need to take some specif fields (OccurrenceDate, Path, Message and StackTrace) and obvious, the total of occurrences.
I'll post my attempts, just a minute.

Comment: Why are you ordering in the inner query? It does not add anything except to make it more complex. You can just replace the inner query with just the table tbllog and the result should be similar, and it will make your Linq query a lot more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Create a linq query out of the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tbllog ORDER BY OccurrenceDate DESC AS result1
GROUP BY result1.Path, result1.Message ORDER BY total DESC
```

Once that is done, write some linq to get your counts.

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = _dbContext.tbllog
    .GroupBy( t => new { t.Path, t.Message })
    .Select( g => new 
        {
            Total = g.Count(),
            Path = g.Key.Path,
            Message = g.Key.Message
        }).OrderBy(p => p.Total);
```

It is worth to mention that your sql query is invalid because the properties `OccurrenceDate` and `StackTrace` is not in the `GROUP BY` clause nor with in an aggregate function, therefore it is invalid query. The same with the LINQ query. You should determine what you want to do with them. Either include them in the group by or use an aggregate function to select the appropriate value for each group.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the context is for your question, but if you don't need to modify the query such that it executes with additional parameters, I would highly recommend executing the query as SQL. This is supported on all the ORMs that I am aware of (Entity Framework, NHiberate, LINQ to SQL, etc).

Erick